# Not building for Android, only IOS after implement react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am working on a project that implements Google Maps and I am using react-native-maps. It worked fine for IOS, because I am use the ios maps, but I am facing issues on Android.

Error message on Android Studio:

````
   Dependency path 'TripPlanner:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.7' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
   Dependency path 'TripPlanner:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.7' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
   Dependency path 'TripPlanner:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.7' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
   Dependency path 'TripPlanner:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.7' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
   Dependency path 'TripPlanner:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.4' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.4' --> 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0'
   Dependency path 'TripPlanner:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.7' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
   Dependency path 'TripPlanner:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.7' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
   Constraint path 'TripPlanner:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations' strictly '24.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 24.0.0
   Constraint path 'TripPlanner:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations' strictly '24.0.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 24.0.0```

Please, let me know which files you need for view my issue.
````